# How to filter rows independently in AG-grid tree data?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm actually checking the documentation on filtering in AG-Grid, specifically focusing on tree data: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/tree-data/ In the demo section titled "Example: Organisational Hierarchy," I made adjustments to the example code by adding: `filter: 'agTextColumnFilter'` in the defaultColDef to have a basic filter option in each column.

When attempting to filter for rows with "Erica Rogers" in the "Organisation Hierarchy" column and "Sales Executive" in the "Job Title", the resulting dataset is empty. However, the issue is that I don't want that output and I don't know how to counter this behavior, I would like my grid to display tree data with these filters by applying them idependently.

I get why this is happening. It's because the filters have a "AND" logic between them. So, I don't have any result because there is no row with "Erica Rogers" in the "Organisation Hierarchy" column AND "Sales Executive" in the "Job Title".

I think the solution would be to apply each filter independently while taking the view updated by the previous filters. I tried to create custom filters for each column of my grid but at some point, I'm unable to get the view updated by the previous filters.

The issue is that, in the documentation, I didn't manage to find the solution to solve my problem. My goal is to be able to filter rows independently. Is it possible with the current ag-grid tree data ?